# Convert numpy array with NaN values to 1e-9 values, (trouble with coherency matrix conversion)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, nan

I am currently processing RADARSAT2 images to visualise targets on the images. I am doing this through using detection algorithms, each output of which is a numpy array.

These numpy arrays output with a lot of NaN values that I want to change into 1e-9 values. The reason is because I need to change a singular matrix into a full rank matrix.

the main issue is that when applying on a T4 matrix (which is a coherency matrix), the error message is that the input matrix is singular when the numpy arrays of my detector algorithms want to take the inverse matrix.

Therefore it was suggested that I 'regularise' the matrix by adding small elements in the diagonal when I have NaN in the array.

However I have not been able to solve this issue. I expected that to change nan values into 1e-9 for each element of the matrix that I could use the following code:

```
C11[np.isnan(C11)] = 1e-9 
C12[np.isnan(C12)] = 0 
C13[np.isnan(C13)] = 0 
C22[np.isnan(C22)] = 1e-9 
C23[np.isnan(C23)] = 0 
C33[np.isnan(C33)] = 1e-9
```

But this has in fact, not changed anything

The function for the matrix is:

```
def All_matrix_distances(images, params):    
    
    [C11, C22, C33, C12, C13, C23] = images
    [win_test, win_guard, win_train, flag] = params
    

    dim = np.shape(C11) 
    dimr = dim[1] 
    dima = dim[0] 
        
    # the kernel for the test area
    kernel_test  = np.ones((win_test, win_test),np.float32)/(win_test**2) #without guard windows
        
    # the kernel for the train area
    if flag == True:

        winGuardLength = int(math.ceil(win_guard))
        nbCellsGuardWindow = winGuardLength**2
        winTrainLength = int(math.ceil(win_train))
        winGuardDistance = int(winTrainLength-winGuardLength/2)
        winTrainSize = [winTrainLength, winTrainLength]
        
        kernel_train  = np.ones((winTrainSize[0],winTrainSize[1]),np.float32)/(winTrainSize[0]*winTrainSize[1]-nbCellsGuardWindow) 
        kernel_train[winGuardDistance:winGuardDistance+winGuardLength,winGuardDistance:winGuardDistance+winGuardLength] = 0
    
    else:
        kernel_train = np.ones((win_train, win_train),np.float32)/(win_train**2) #without guard windows
    


    C11_sm = signal.convolve2d(C11,kernel_test,mode='same', boundary='wrap', fillvalue=0) 
    C22_sm = signal.convolve2d(C22,kernel_test,mode='same', boundary='wrap', fillvalue=0) 
    C33_sm = signal.convolve2d(C33,kernel_test,mode='same', boundary='wrap', fillvalue=0) 
    C12_sm = signal.convolve2d(C12,kernel_test,mode='same', boundary='wrap', fillvalue=0) 
    C13_sm = signal.convolve2d(C13,kernel_test,mode='same', boundary='wrap', fillvalue=0) 
    C23_sm = signal.convolve2d(C23,kernel_test,mode='same', boundary='wrap', fillvalue=0) 

    C11_tr = signal.convolve2d(C11,kernel_train,mode='same', boundary='wrap', fillvalue=0) 
    C22_tr = signal.convolve2d(C22,kernel_train,mode='same', boundary='wrap', fillvalue=0) 
    C33_tr = signal.convolve2d(C33,kernel_train,mode='same', boundary='wrap', fillvalue=0) 
    C12_tr = signal.convolve2d(C12,kernel_train,mode='same', boundary='wrap', fillvalue=0) 
    C13_tr = signal.convolve2d(C13,kernel_train,mode='same', boundary='wrap', fillvalue=0) 
    C23_tr = signal.convolve2d(C23,kernel_train,mode='same', boundary='wrap', fillvalue=0) 

    # creating the asymptotic matrix for the target
    T_tar = np.matrix('1 0 0; 0 6 0; 0 0 8')      
    invT_tar = ln.inv(T_tar)
    
    T = np.zeros((3,3), dtype=np.complex64) 
    T_tr = np.zeros((3,3), dtype=np.complex64) 

    lam1_PMF = np.zeros((dima,dimr))
    lam3_PMF = np.zeros((dima,dimr))
    PWF = np.zeros((dima,dimr))  #assign the variable to the function to avoid a TypeError
    OPD = np.zeros((dima,dimr))  #assign the variable to the function to avoid a TypeError

for i in range(0, dima-1):
        for ii in range(0, dimr-1):             
            T[0,0] = C11_sm[i,ii]     
            T[1,1] = C22_sm[i,ii]                   
            T[2,2] = C33_sm[i,ii]             
            T[0,1] = C12_sm[i,ii]             
            T[1,0] = np.conj(T[0,1])             
            T[0,2] = C13_sm[i,ii]             
            T[2,0] = np.conj(T[0,2])             
            T[1,2] = C23_sm[i,ii]                   
            T[2,1] = np.conj(T[1,2])        

            T_tr[0,0] = C11_tr[i,ii]     
            T_tr[1,1] = C22_tr[i,ii]                   
            T_tr[2,2] = C33_tr[i,ii]             
            T_tr[0,1] = C12_tr[i,ii]             
            T_tr[1,0] = np.conj(T_tr[0,1])             
            T_tr[0,2] = C13_tr[i,ii]             
            T_tr[2,0] = np.conj(T_tr[0,2])             
            T_tr[1,2] = C23_tr[i,ii]                   
            T_tr[2,1] = np.conj(T_tr[1,2])        
            
            print (npl.matrix_rank(T_tr))
            invT_tr = ln.inv(T_tr)

 # PMF  #################################################
            A_PMF = np.matmul(invT_tr, T)
            [d, v] = ln.eigh(A_PMF)
            
            lam1_PMF[i,ii] = np.abs(np.max(d))
            lam3_PMF[i,ii] = np.abs(1./np.min(d))


            # PWF ################################################# 
            A_PWF = A_PMF
            PWF[i,ii] = np.abs(np.trace(A_PWF))


            # OPD ################################################# 
            deltaT = invT_tr - invT_tar
            A_OPD = np.matmul(deltaT, T)
            
            OPD[i,ii] = np.abs(np.trace(A_OPD))


          

        print(dima-i)
    


    return lam1_PMF, lam3_PMF, PWF, OPD
```

The function itself works fine. But when I assign it, I get the error when it runs the line

```
invT_tr = ln.inv(T_tr)
```

Here is the entire script where I assign the function to:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:\\MyC\\Programs\\Sonny\\')


# The first step is to import all the library that we will be using in our script
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import rasterio as r
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
import numpy.linalg as npl

import SAR_Utilities_June2020 as sar
import SAR_Detectors_18June2020 as det
import sys
plt.close('all')


path_save = 'D:\\Iceberg data\\RADARSAT\\'


# Select here the image tat you are processing
#flag_image = '20160415' 
#flag_image = '20160416' 
#flag_image = '20160417'
#flag_image = 'radarsat4'
#
#if flag_image == '20160415': 
    #image_name = 'r1'
    #path='D:\\Iceberg data\\ALOS-2\\Saved\\ALOS2-HBQR1_1__A-ORBIT__ALOS2066231360-150815_Cal_ML\\'
#if flag_image == '20160416': 
    #image_name = 'r2'
    #path='D:\\Iceberg data\\ALOS-2\\Saved\\ALOS2-HBQR1_1__A-ORBIT__ALOS2064761430-150805_Cal_ML\\'
#if flag_image == '20160417': 
   #image_name = 'r3'
   #path='D:\\Iceberg data\ALOS-2\\Saved\\ALOS2-HBQR1_1__A-ORBIT__ALOS2064461300-150803_Cal_ML\\'
#if flag_image == 'radarsat4': 
   #image_name = 'r4' 
   #path ='D:\\Iceberg data\\ALOS-2\\Saved\\ALOS2-HBQR1_1__A-ORBIT__ALOS2191031530-171206_Cal_ML\\'

    
# Select here if you wantr to start from beginning
flag_processing = "From beginning"
#flag_processing = "From multilook"

flag_image = '20160415'

if flag_image == '20160415':
    image_name = 'r1'
    path=r'D:\\Iceberg data\\RADARSAT\\RS2_Stack.tif\\'

raster = r.open(path)

print(raster)
raster.bounds
raster.height
raster.width
raster.transform
raster.get_transform()
raster.tags(1)
xmin=raster.bounds[0]
ymax=raster.bounds[3]

#HH=raster.read(1)+(1j*raster.read(2))
#VV=raster.read(2)+(1j*raster.read(3))
#HV=raster.read(3)+(1j*raster.read(4))

T11_april15 = raster.read(1)
T12_april15 = raster.read(2)+(1j*raster.read(3)) 
T13_april15 = raster.read(4)+(1j*raster.read(5))
T14_april15 = raster.read(6)+(1j*raster.read(7))
T22_april15 = raster.read(8)
T23_april15 = raster.read(9)+(1j*raster.read(10))
T24_april15 = raster.read(11)+(1j*raster.read(12))
T33_april15 = raster.read(13)
T34_april15 = raster.read(14)+(1j*raster.read(15)) 
T44_april15 = raster.read(16)
land_april15 = raster.read(17)
target_april15 = raster.read(18)
clutter_april15 = raster.read(19)
tcm_april15 = raster.read(20)

T11_april16 = raster.read(21)
T12_april16 = raster.read(22)+(1j*raster.read(23)) 
T13_april16 = raster.read(24)+(1j*raster.read(25))
T22_april16 = raster.read(26)
T23_april16 = raster.read(27)+(1j*raster.read(28))
T33_april16 = raster.read(19)
land_april16 = raster.read(30)
target_april16 = raster.read(31)
clutter_april16 = raster.read(32)
tcm_april16 = raster.read(33)

T11_april17 = raster.read(34)
T12_april17 = raster.read(35)+(1j*raster.read(36)) 
T13_april17 = raster.read(37)+(1j*raster.read(38))
T22_april17 = raster.read(39)
T23_april17 = raster.read(40)+(1j*raster.read(41))
T33_april17 = raster.read(42)
land_april17 = raster.read(43)
target_april17 = raster.read(44)
clutter_april17 = raster.read(45)
tcm_april17 = raster.read(46)





#fig = plt.figure(1)
#plt.title('SLC image')      # this defines the title 


#visualising an image for reference
#plt.imshow(np.abs(HH[:,:]), cmap = 'gray', vmin = 0, vmax = np.abs(HH[:,:]).mean()*2)
#plt.imshow(np.abs(VV[:,:]), cmap = 'gray', vmin = 0, vmax = np.abs(VV[:,:]).mean()*2)
#plt.imshow(np.abs(HV[:,:]), cmap = 'gray', vmin = 0, vmax = np.abs(HV[:,:]).mean()*2)


{i: dtype for i, dtype in zip(raster.indexes, raster.dtypes)}




#%%
if flag_processing == "From beginning":
      
    print('Producing covariance matrix from the start...')    

    #############################################################################
    #
    #                       LOADING DATA IN ENVI FORMAT
    #
    ################### PUT HERE THE CODE TO READ THE S MATRIX AND THE C MATRIX 
    

    
    
    #############################################################################
    #
    #                        Consider a subset of the image
    #
    #
    #############################################################################
    


    
    
    #############################################################################
    #
    #                      BOXCAR FILTERING 
    #
    #
    #############################################################################
    
    # Deciding the window
    win = [3, 3]
    # This is because the azimuth resolution is 4 times higher. 
    win1 = np.int(win[0])
    win2 = np.int(win[1])
    kernel  = np.ones((win1,win2))/(win1*win2)

    
    
    ######## C11 ##################
    C11_full = signal.convolve2d(np.abs(T11_april15)**2, kernel, mode='same', boundary='fill', fillvalue=0)
    C11 = np.abs(C11_full[::win1,::win2])
    del C11_full
    
    C12_full = signal.convolve2d(T11_april15*np.conj(T22_april15), kernel, mode='same', boundary='fill', fillvalue=0)
    C12 = C12_full[::win1,::win2]
    del C12_full
    
    C13_full = signal.convolve2d(T11_april15*np.conj(T33_april15), kernel, mode='same', boundary='fill', fillvalue=0)
    C13 = C13_full[::win1,::win2]    
    del C13_full

    del T11_april15
    
    C22_full = signal.convolve2d(np.abs(T22_april15)*2, kernel, mode='same', boundary='fill', fillvalue=0)
    C22 = np.abs(C22_full[::win1,::win2])
    del C22_full
    
    C23_full = signal.convolve2d(T22_april15*np.conj(T33_april15), kernel, mode='same', boundary='fill', fillvalue=0)
    C23 = C23_full[::win1,::win2]
    del C23_full
    
    del T22_april15
    
    C33_full = signal.convolve2d(np.abs(T33_april15)**2, kernel, mode='same', boundary='fill', fillvalue=0)
    C33 = np.abs(C33_full[::win1,::win2])
    del C33_full
    
    del T33_april15
    
    np.save(path_save + 'C_lexi_' + image_name + '_5x5', [C11, C22, C33, C12, C13, C23])



print('Reading pre-stored covariance matrix...')    
[C11, C22, C33, C12, C13, C23] = np.load(path_save + 'C_lexi_' + image_name + '_5x5.npy')


# normalising the elements to avoid numerical problem
# this is not nneeded if data is in sigma naught

#def norm(band):
    #band_min, band_max = band.min(), band.max()
    #return ((band - band_min)/(band_max - band_min))

#C11 = norm(C11)
#C12 = norm(C12)
#C13 = norm(C13)
#C21 = norm(C21)
#C22 = norm(C22)
#C23 = norm(C23)
#C31 = norm(C31)
#C32 = norm(C32)
#C33 = norm(C33)

#normalizer = (1e1*np.mean(C11))
#C11 = np.abs(C11)/normalizer 
#C22 = np.abs(C22)/normalizer 
#C33 = np.abs(C33)/normalizer 
#C12 = C12/normalizer 
#C13 = C13/normalizer 
#C23 = C23/normalizer 

C11[np.isnan(C11)] = 1e-9 
C12[np.isnan(C12)] = 0 
C13[np.isnan(C13)] = 0 
C22[np.isnan(C22)] = 1e-9 
C23[np.isnan(C23)] = 0 
C33[np.isnan(C33)] = 1e-9 
#########################################################





 
# get the dimensions
dim1 = np.shape(C11)[0]
dim2 = np.shape(C11)[1]




#%%
############################################################################# 
#  
#               Convert to Pauli
#
#############################################################################

flag_basis = 'Pauli'
flag_basis = 'Lexi'

if flag_basis == 'Pauli':
    print('Converting to Pauli basis...')    
    C = np.zeros((2,2), dtype=np.complex64)
    for i in range(0, dim1):
        for ii in range(0, dim2):                         
            C[0,0] = C11[i,ii]
            C[1,1] = C22[i,ii]
            C[2,2] = C33[i,ii]     
            C[0,1] = C12[i,ii]     
            C[1,0] = np.conj(C[0,1])     
            C[0,2] = C13[i,ii]
            C[2,0] = np.conj(C[0,2])     
            C[1,2] = C23[i,ii]
            C[2,1] = np.conj(C[1,2])     
                   
            #if (polCat == "co"):
            T = sar.similTransf(C) 
            C11[i,ii] = T[0,0]
            C22[i,ii] = T[1,1]
            C33[i,ii] = T[2,2]
            C12[i,ii] = T[0,1]
            C13[i,ii] = T[0,2]
            C23[i,ii] = T[1,2]



############# RGB ##################
iRGB = np.zeros([dim1, dim2, 3])          # Create an empty 3D array (full of zeros) 

fact = 3.5

iRGB[:,:,2] = np.abs(C11)/(C11.mean()*fact)
iRGB[:,:,0] = np.abs(C22)/(C22.mean()*fact)
iRGB[:,:,1] = np.abs(C33)/(C33.mean()*fact)
iRGB[np.abs(iRGB) > 1] = 1

fig = plt.figure(2)
plt.title('RGB image')      # this defines the title 
plt.imshow(iRGB)
del iRGB

#%%##############################################################################
##  
##               Detectors 
##
###############################################################################
################# HERE RUN THE DETECTORS ONE AFTER THE OTHER: e.g.
## check in the code what are all these parameters you need

win_test = 3       # 3
win_train = 11      # 51
win_guard = 7      # 41
flag = True

# Symmetry detector
#kernel  = np.ones((win_test,win_test)/(win_test*win_test)
#sym = np.abs( signal.convolve2d(C12, kernel, mode='same', boundary='fill', fillvalue=0) )
sym = np.abs(C12)

images = [C11, C22]
params = [win_test, win_guard, win_train, flag]
print('Processing iDPolRAD...')    
[iDPolRAD, DPolRAD] = det.iDPolRAD(images, params)



#%%  
print('Processing Notch Filter quad and dual...')    
images = [C11, C22, C33, C12, C13, C23]
RR = 1
params = [win_test, win_guard, win_train, RR, flag]
Notch = det.Notch(images, params)

images = [C11, C22, C12]
PNFd = det.Notch_dual(images, params)

sar.vis4(iDPolRAD, DPolRAD, Notch, sym, 
         title1 = 'iDPolRAD', 
         title2 = 'DPolRAD',
         title3 = 'Notch', 
         title4 = 'Symmetry', 
         scale1 = [0, 3*np.mean(iDPolRAD)], 
         scale2 = [0, 3*np.mean(DPolRAD)],
         scale3 = [0, 0.25], 
         scale4 = [0, 3*np.mean(sym)],  
         flag = 0, 
         outall = [],
         colormap = 'gray')


#%%   
print('Processing entropy...')    
images = [C11, C22, C33, C12, C13, C23]
params = [win_test]

[H, al, lam1, lam3] = det.Entropy(images, params)
alpha = np.pi/2-al
sar.vis4(H, alpha, lam1, lam3, 
         title1 = 'H', 
         title2 = 'alpha',
         title3 = 'lambda1', 
         title4 = 'lambda3', 
         scale1 = [0, 1], 
         scale2 = [0, np.pi/2],
         scale3 = [0, 3*np.mean(lam1)], 
         scale4 = [0, 3*np.mean(lam3)],  
         flag = 0, 
         outall = [],
         colormap = 'gray')



#%%
print('PMF, PWF, OPD...')
images = [C11, C22, C33, C12, C13, C23]
params = [win_test, win_guard, win_train, flag]

[sig1, sig3, PWF, OPD] = det.All_matrix_distances(images, params)


sar.vis4(sig1, sig3, PWF, OPD,
         title1 = 'Sigma1', 
         title2 = 'Sigma3',
         title3 = 'PWF',
         title4 = 'OPD',
         scale1 = [0, 20], 
         scale2 = [0, 3*np.mean(sig3)],
         scale3 = [0, 20],
         scale4 = [0, 30],
         flag = 0, 
         outall = [],
         colormap = 'gray')







# To save the detector images 
flag_save_det = 'True'
#flag_save_det = 'False'
if flag_save_det == 'True':
    np.savez(path_save + 'Detectors_' + str(win_test) + str(win_train) + 'guard' + image_name, 
            win_test, win_train, iDPolRAD, DPolRAD, sym, Notch, H, alpha, lam1, lam3, sig1, sig3, PWF, OPD)
```

Ignore the first part of the script. That is extracting the data which is fine. I should mention that one of the images is in T4 format while the other two are in T3 format. They are stacked together and the rasters are able to be read.

But with the matrix conversion, and the NaN values that each detector output shows, that is where I know there is an error, but I can't figure out how to correct this in order to get the full thing to run.

Can anyone suggest some tips for singular to full rank matrix here?

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I figured it out.

```
C11[np.isnan(C11)] = 1e-9 
C12[np.isnan(C12)] = 0 
C13[np.isnan(C13)] = 0 
C22[np.isnan(C22)] = 1e-9 
C23[np.isnan(C23)] = 0 
C33[np.isnan(C33)] = 1e-9
```

This code assumed that my C11, C22 and C33 arrays had NaN values in them. They did not. Therefore I was getting a singular matrix error.

Instead I changed the code to this:

```
C11[C11 == 0] = 1e-9 
C12[np.isnan(C12)] = 0 
C13[np.isnan(C13)] = 0 
C22[C22 == 0] = 1e-9 
C23[np.isnan(C23)] = 0 
C33[C33 == 0] = 1e-9
```

Since I am working with booleans, I used the == operator and then added the 1e-9 value which allowed the matrix to be inversed.

It was an annoying fix which took many days to solve.